How to get the max daily value from a set of half-hourly records between "9:30" (Day 0) to "9:00" (Day 1) instead of "0:00" to "23:30" each day
I have the following dataframe df
         Local_Time_Dt             Value
0        1999-02-22 07:30:00       1.5
1        1999-02-22 08:00:00       3.9
2        1999-02-22 08:30:00       3.9
3        1999-02-22 09:00:00       3.9
4        1999-02-22 09:30:00       2.0
... ...
421208   2023-03-03 11:30:00       0
421209   2023-03-03 12:00:00       0
421210   2023-03-03 12:30:00       0
421211   2023-03-03 13:00:00       0
421212   2023-03-03 13:30:00       0

The type of the column "Local_Time_Dt" is datetime64[ns] (half-hourly) and Value is float.
What I want to achieve to get the daily max Value between "09:30:00" of previous day to "09:00:00" of current day instead of from "00:00:00" to "23:30:00".
The problems are some days might miss records which could stop the rolling function from working in this case; and some days might have duplicated half-hourly records due to daylight saving.
The desired output would be:
        Local_Time_Dt             Value
0       1999-02-22                 3.9
1       1999-02-23                 4.0
... ...

8775    2023-03-03                 0

I am not sure what function I should use in Pandas.

Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre]. E.g., use df.head().to_dict() for your dfs, so that SO users can easily work with your sample. Please post both a minimal sample as well as the desired output based on that actual sample. E.g., your current "desired output" has values that we cannot trace based on your input (with ... ...).

You can add 14.5h (24h - 9h30) to align your datetime to the days as desired:
out = df.groupby(df['Local_Time_Dt'].add(pd.Timedelta('14h30min')).dt.normalize())['Value'].max()

NB. you can also use pd.Timedelta('-9.5h+1d') in place of pd.Timedelta('14h30min').
Output:
Local_Time_Dt
1999-02-22    3.9
1999-02-23    2.0
2023-03-04    0.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64

Here is a breakdown of the logic with a more meaningful minimal example:
         Local_Time_Dt  Value               +14.5h   normalize   max?
0  1999-02-22 07:30:00      7  1999-02-22 22:00:00  1999-02-22   True
1  1999-02-22 09:30:00      6  1999-02-23 00:00:00  1999-02-23   True
2  1999-02-22 10:00:00      5  1999-02-23 00:30:00  1999-02-23  False
3  1999-02-23 01:00:00      4  1999-02-23 15:30:00  1999-02-23  False
4  1999-02-23 07:30:00      3  1999-02-23 22:00:00  1999-02-23  False
5  1999-02-23 09:00:00      2  1999-02-23 23:30:00  1999-02-23  False
6  1999-02-23 09:30:00      1  1999-02-24 00:00:00  1999-02-24   True

